# How to use X-Robots-Tag to noindex all subdomains (save specific exceptions)?

Tags: htaccess, apache, subdomain, noindex

Google's [Robots meta tag and X-Robots-Tag HTTP header specifications](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag) page (*Practical implementation of X-Robots-Tag with Apache* section) gives an example of `noindex`ing certain filetypes, ie:

```
<Files ~ "\.pdf$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

But I can't find any explanation on how to apply an `X-Robots-Tag` directive to all subdomains, save certain exceptions, eg `docs.example.com`.

PS - In my case there is only one root folder (using WordPress multisite, which shares file structure across the network).

Comment: Do all your subdomains point to the same directory on the filesystem? ie. do they all point to the document root of the main domain?

Comment: Yes, this is a WordPress multisite installation so the file system is all the same! Thanks for asking good question. I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Since all the subdomains point to the same place on the filesystem then you can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^docs\. INDEX
SetEnvIf Host ^foo\. INDEX
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=!INDEX
```

This uses mod_setenvif to conditionally set an environment variable `INDEX` for the subdomains you wish to allow indexing, ie. that you do not want to set the `X-Robots-Tag` header. The subdomains are identified by checking the `Host` HTTP request header. The `noindex` `X-Robots-Tag` header is then only set if this environment variable is *not* set.

Note that this will currently set the `noindex` `X-Robots-Tag` on the domain apex (ie. `example.com`) and www subdomains as well. To exclude the main domain then add another exception:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^(www\.)?example\.com INDEX
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "^doc\." x_tag=yes
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=x_tag
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```